# How to find $\Phi^{-1}(\beta)$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I need to find  $\Phi^{-1}(\beta)$ when $\beta=0.1$ (or any number but for example) but I'm not quite sure how to find it using the normal table inversely like this. I've tried googling and looking through notes and while it should be relatively simple I'm a bit lost. Can anyone provide assistance?

Comment: Check whether your mathematical software offers a function called `norminv()` or `normcdfinv()`, which computes the inverse of the standard normal distribution. If that does not exist, check whether the inverse of the (complementary) error function is available, e.g. `erfinv()`, `inverf()` or `erfcinv()`, `inverfc()`, from which you can compute $\Phi^{-1}$ by straightforward mathematical identities. For accurate computation of the tails, you will need to compute via the inverse of the complementary error function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several versions of the standard normal table, and I do not know which one you are using.

The most common version gives $\Phi(z)$ for $z$ ranging from $z=0$ to about $z=3.5$. You can check whether you are using this sort of table by looking up the entry under $z=0$. It should be $0.5$.

If we look in the **body** of this table, we find that $\Phi(z)=0.9$ at $z\approx 1.28$. So the area in the *right tail* from $z=1.28$ on is about $0.1$.

By symmetry, the area in the *left tail* from $-\infty$ to $-1.28$ is about $0.1$. Thus $\Phi(0.1)\approx -1.28$.